# Clojure macroexpand

Tags: macros, clojure

Why does

```
(macroexpand '(.. arm getHand getFinger))
```

expand to

```
(. (. arm getHand) getFinger)
```

while

```
(macroexpand '(-> arm getHand getFinger))
```

expands to

```
(getFinger (clojure.core/-> arm getHand))
```

In other words, why is the `->` not expanding fully in the second example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`macroexpand` only expands the form until the symbol in the function position is not a macro. The reason why you notice this in the case of `->` is because the `->` macro is recursive.

In your case, you want `macroexpand-all` form clojure.walk

Comment: That's actually why I asked. Shouldn't `macroexpand` have expanded `->` until it was not a macro? I looked at the source code for `->` and it appears to eventually resolve to "([x form] (if (seq? form) (with-meta `(~(first form) ~x ~@(next form)) (meta form)) (list form x)))" Maybe I'm not understanding it correctly.

Comment: @Ralph: `macroexpand` does not expand macros in subforms, so `(-> arm getHand getFinger)` expands to `(clojure.core/-> (clojure.core/-> arm getHand) getFinger)` which expands (because -> is a macro) to `(getFinger (clojure.core/-> arm getHand))`. The expansion stops here because `getFinger` is not a macro.