# Passing compile-time state between nested macros in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros, nested, state

I'm trying to write a macro that can be used both in a global and nested way, like so:

```
;;; global:
(do-stuff 1)

;;; nested, within a "with-context" block:
(with-context {:foo :bar}
  (do-stuff 2)
  (do-stuff 3))
```

When used in the nested way, `do-stuff` should have access to `{:foo :bar}` set by `with-context`.

I've been able to implement it like this:

```
(def ^:dynamic *ctx* nil)

(defmacro with-context [ctx & body]
  `(binding [*ctx* ~ctx]
     (do ~@body)))

(defmacro do-stuff [v]
  `(if *ctx*
     (println "within context" *ctx* ":" ~v)
     (println "no context:" ~v)))
```

However, I've been trying to shift the `if` within `do-stuff` from runtime to compile-time, because whether `do-stuff` is being called from within the body of `with-context` or globally is an information that's already available at compile-time.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a solution, because nested macros seem to get expanded in multiple "macro expansion runs", so the dynamic binding of `*ctx*` (as set within `with-context`) is not available anymore when `do-stuff` gets expanded. So this does not work:

```
(def ^:dynamic *ctx* nil)

(defmacro with-context [ctx & body]
  (binding [*ctx* ctx]
    `(do ~@body)))

(defmacro do-stuff [v]
  (if *ctx*
    `(println "within context" ~*ctx* ":" ~v)
    `(println "no context:" ~v)))
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Or is my approach totally insane and there's a pattern for how to pass state in such a way from one macro to a nested one?

**EDIT**:

The body of `with-context` should be able to work with arbitrary expressions, not only with `do-stuff` (or other context aware functions/macros). So something like this should also be possible:

```
(with-context {:foo :bar}
  (do-stuff 2)
  (some-arbitrary-function)
  (do-stuff 3))
```

(I'm aware that `some-arbitrary-function` is about side effects, it might write something to a database for example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the code is being macroexpanded, Clojure [computes](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/e547d35bb796051bb2cbf07bbca6ee67c5bc022f/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3978) a [fixpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)):

```
(defn macroexpand
  "Repeatedly calls macroexpand-1 on form until it no longer
  represents a macro form, then returns it.  Note neither
  macroexpand-1 nor macroexpand expand macros in subforms."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [form]
    (let [ex (macroexpand-1 form)]
      (if (identical? ex form)
        form
        (macroexpand ex))))
```

Any binding you establish during the execution of a macro is no more in place when you exit your macro (this happens inside `macroexpand-1`). By the time an inner macro is being expanded, the context is long gone.

But, you can call `macroexpand` directly, in which case the binding are still effective. Note however that in your case, you probably need to call [`macroexpand-all`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/macroexpand-all).
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304715/124319) explains the differences between `macroexpand` and `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all`:  basically, you need to make sure all inner forms are macroexanded.
The source code for `macroexpand-all` shows [how it is implemented](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/walk.clj#L125).

So, you can implement your macro as follows:

```
(defmacro with-context [ctx form]
  (binding [*ctx* ctx]
    (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all form)))
```

In that case, the dynamic bindings should be visible from inside the inner macros.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was searching for, thank you! Fun fact: I have indeed tried this with `macroexpand` and `macroexpand-1` but it didn't work. I simply wasn't aware of `macroexpand-all`. Thanks a lot. However, I'm wondering whether my idea of passing state like this between macros is conceptually proper. Calling something like `macroexpand` from within code always feels awkward. Am I missing an idiom here that would solve my problem in a better (more idiomatic, cleaner) way?

Comment: I have no objection about it: after all, the function is made available so that you can use it. It is a little bit unusual, so you have to provide a good documentation to `with-context`, `*ctx*` as well as any macro that depends on it. It is a form of coupling, but if you need it, it works. I don't know of anything "cleaner" than that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep it simple.
This is solution avoids state in an additional `*ctx*` variable. I think it is a more functional approach.

```
(defmacro do-stuff 
  ([arg1 context]
    `(do (prn :arg1 ~arg1 :context ~context))
         {:a 4 :b 5})
  ([arg1]
    `(prn :arg1 ~arg1 :no-context)))

(->> {:a 3 :b 4}
     (do-stuff 1)
     (do-stuff 2))
```

output:

```
:arg1 1 :context {:a 3, :b 4}
:arg1 2 :context {:b 5, :a 4}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's really simple and more functional, you're right. However, this only works when using `do-stuff` (or other context-aware functions/macros) within the threading macro block. What if I'd like to be able to use arbitrary functions/macros in that body that don't accept context as a last parameter? E.g. `(->> {:a 3 :b 4} (do-stuff 1) (with-open [r stream] ...))`. Any ideas? (Sorry, my original question indeed has not mentioned this is a requirement, as I was trying to make the examples as simple as possible).

Answer (score 1):

there is one more variant to do this, using some macro magic:

```
(defmacro with-context [ctx & body]
  (let [ctx (eval ctx)]
    `(let [~'&ctx ~ctx]
       (binding [*ctx* ~ctx]
         (do ~@body)))))
```

in this definition we introduce another `let` binding for `ctx`. Clojure's macro system would then put it into the `&env` variable, accessible by the inner macros at compile-time. Notice that we also keep `bindings` so that inner functions could use it.

now we need to define the function to get the context value from macro's `&env`:

```
(defn env-ctx [env]
  (some-> env ('&ctx) .init .eval))
```

and then you can easily define `do-stuff`:

```
(defmacro do-stuff [v]
  (if-let [ctx (env-ctx &env)]
    `(println "within context" ~ctx ":" ~v)
    `(println "no context:" ~v)))
```

in repl:

```
user> (defn my-fun []
        (println "context in fn is: " *ctx*))
#'user/my-fun

user> (defmacro my-macro []
        `(do-stuff 100))
#'user/my-macro

user> (with-context {:a 10 :b 20}
        (do-stuff 1)
        (my-fun)
        (my-macro)
        (do-stuff 2))
;;within context {:a 10, :b 20} : 1
;;context in fn is:  {:a 10, :b 20}
;;within context {:a 10, :b 20} : 100
;;within context {:a 10, :b 20} : 2
nil

user> (do (do-stuff 1)
          (my-fun)
          (my-macro)
          (do-stuff 2))
;;no context: 1
;;context in fn is:  nil
;;no context: 100
;;no context: 2
nil
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a very interesting solution, somewhat more involved. I'm just wondering if it's a good idea to rely on the implementation of the `&env` values (via assuming there are methods like `.init` and `.eval`). But nevertheless, this gives an interesting insight into how you can benefit from `&env` in macros.